# WordPress Plugin: Instead of redirecting, use include

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I'm working on a WP plugin which *redirects* the user when maintenance is enabled;

```
if( ! is_page( intval( $maintenance_options['page'] ) ) ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $maintenance_options['page'] ) ); exit;
}
```

I rather not redirect the user, but `include` the page. This example is totally wrong, but just to clear it up:

```
include($maintenance_options['page']);
```

... so the user stays on the index instead of a slash page.

Is that possible, is it safe and how can I execute it?

Answer (score 0):

There's an [action hook for this purpose](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/template_include) called `template_include`:

> This filter hook is executed immediately before WordPress includes the predetermined template file. This can be used to override WordPress's default template behavior.

An example:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'maintenance_template', 99 );
function maintenance_template( $template ) {
    if( ! is_page( intval( $maintenance_options['page'] ) ) ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'path-to-template-relative-to-theme-root.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: Good to know, thank you. What do they mean with `path-to-template-relative-to-theme-root.php`?

Comment: I'm not sure who "they" is. I wrote that as a placeholder. You need to replace that path with an actual path to a template. That template path is relative to the theme root directory.

Comment: So this also allows me to give the user a blank page template? That would be something I need aswell!